# Activity Transition using Intents?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

The activity transition is like this

A -----------> B (`startActivity`)

B -----------> C (`startActivityOnResult`)

When i set Result in Activity in C and perform finish(), i'm redirected to activity A ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Edit:
A -------- B

```
startActivity(new intent(uri,Search.class)`
```

B -------- C

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ContactsPicker.class);
intent.putExtra("Mode", 2);
startActivityForResult(intent,ContactsPicker.RECENT_CONTACTS);
```

In Activty C:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("contactlist",str.toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);  
finish();
```

Comment: show the code that tansmit from A to B and from B to C

Comment: What is the problem? You did not state a problem or what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

1. use `startActivityForResult()` method in your parent Activity A while calling activity B.
2. override `onStop()` or `onDestory()` methods in your child activities B and C and set an arbitrary result code, say '2'. You can do it the following way:

   ```
   protected void onStop() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     setResult(2);
     super.onStop();
   }
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     setResult(2);
     super.onDestroy();
   }
   ```
3. override the `onActivityResult()` method in your activity A and B and finish the activities according to the result code. You can do it the following way:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(resultCode==2){
     finish();
     }
   }
   ```

This should finish all the activities when activity C finishes.

Comment: Exactly it is the main activity.That activity is the landing page for our app.Is it okay to finish each time when A -> B occurs.

Comment: Well, in my opinion it should be ok. Give it a try. or you may try finishing activity A in activity C.

Comment: So siva, did my solution proposal worked for you? Please provide us a feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Korhan Öztürk but it didnt work for me.Actually the Activity B  gets destroyed when B --> C takes place.so when finish is called from C, Activity A resumes, instead of B